# How to join two different tables without using join or union?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

So I have a table 'A' with has column of numerical values of 12 digits, now there is another table 'B' which has only first 6 digits of the same numerical value, I want to join both the tables using the first 6 digits of table 'A' and already 6 digits of values in table 'B'.

```
SELECT *    
FROM A 
inner join B ON A.K1 = B.K1
```

here `K1` is basically the first 6 digits of the number which I created as a new column in output.

I cannot use `ALTER` as it is a live table.

Comment: have you already taken look on MySQL string functions?

Answer (score 1):

You could just join on the first 6 digits then:

Example data:

Table `test1`:

| id | somestring |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | foo |
| 234567 | bar |
| 345678 | baz |

Table `test2`:

| id | otherstring |
| --- | --- |
| 123456789012 | eenie |
| 234567890123 | meenie |
| 987654321098 | mo |

The statement

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM test1
INNER JOIN test2
        ON test1.id = LEFT(test2.id, 6)
```

will produce

| id | somestring | id | otherstring |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | foo | 123456789012 | eenie |
| 234567 | bar | 234567890123 | meenie |

Test it in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dSP-KD_7).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.*, b.*
from table_a a
full outer join table_b b on 
  to_number(substr(rtrim(ltrim(to_char(a.col_n))),1,6))=b.col_n;
```

That's what I can think of having as much information as you provided. I do not know whether your business requires that it should be an inner join, left/right outer join or full outer join.
Union is a completely different concept: that just reunites into a data set similar columns from different data sets. And there is the simple UNION which makes Oracle to sort and eliminate duplicates and UNION ALL, which takes all the data, including duplicates if any.